# Are there different ways to make the Kalman filter differentiate data?

Tags: derivatives, kalman-filter

I have a kalman filter that estimate 3D position I have in my state position, speed and acceleration.
I only have speed readings so I use it as a measurement update and for the acceleration I get it from my state when the kalman filter differentiates speed.
The thing is I found out that the acceleration derived by the kalman filter is not good as the acceleration derived from speed using finite differences.
My transition matrix is an identity matrix except for the speed which has the acceleration multiplied by time step added to it.
My question is "Is there another way to make the kalman filter differentiate better results or any papers about that?"

Comment: Have you verified your model, which also includes that the measurement and process covariance matrices are picked correctly?

Comment: what do you mean by verifying my model? for the measurement and process covariance matrices I used grid search for the parameters till my estimates were close to the ground truth.

Comment: To implement a KF, you need process and observation models. Please, share these equations. Based on your description, your system doesn't make any sense to me, but I can't say for sure without seeing the models.